# Variable Importance values from Random Forest into PCA

Tags: pca, random-forest

I intend to do some analyses on the relationship between tree growth (chronological series of values indicating the yearly increase in stem radius) and climatic variables. An important point is also to determine if different species have different growth/climate relationship.

One common approach in the field is to use bootstrapped response function (https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0450%281971%29010%3C0845%3AMTFSTG%3E2.0.CO%3B2) to calculate response coefficients. Those response coefficients are then introduced into a Principal Component Analysis. The PCA aims at reducing data dimensionality while retaining as much of the original variation as possible, thus allowing to see if different variables are grouped together and if such grouping discriminates the species. For an example of such method, see https://doi.org/10.1016/j.agrformet.2014.06.001.

In my case, given that I expect to see strongly non-linear climate-growth relationship, I was wondering if I could use Regression Random Forest models to calculate Variable Importance values for each climatic variable and then introduce those VIMP values in a PCA. Are VIMP values suited for this?

To be more precise, RF models would be calculated for each of my 31 study sites separetaley and then, the VIMP values would be introduced into a PCA to discover spatial patterns of growth-climate relationship and differences between species.

Comment: PCA is indeed intended as a dimension reducing method. What's not clear is whether or not it is appropriate for the information you have available. It would help if you were to describe in more detail what information (variables) you have for your model. If you have dozens of factors, then PCA might be advantageous. If not, it could be that random forest importance followed by PCA would mute variance that a more direct ANOVA-type, nonlinear approach on the raw data would better express.

Comment: Several options are possible depending on the climatic variable that would need to be taken into account. But my first impression is that I would use either 19 or 38 variables

Comment: My concern is also about the fact that Variable Importance (VIMP) values are relative. So, does it make sense to calculate VIMP values for X climatic variables in Y study sites and then use PCA to explore the spatial patterns of growth-climate relationship and the differences between species? Shoudn't I divide the VIMP values by the prediction error of the model to make it comparable between sites?